# Vault on k8s without admin rights

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to install the Hashicorp Vault in my k8s available on Openshift environment, but unfortunately I don't have admin rights and the IT department said that it is not possible to provide this admin right.

Is there another option for a vault where it is not necessary admin right for the kubernetes?

The error after the tentative installation is this one.

> Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists.
> Unable to continue with install: could not get information about the
> resource: customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io
> "vaultsecrets.ricoberger.de" is forbidden: User "" cannot get resource
> "customresourcedefinitions" in API group "apiextensions.k8s.io" at the
> cluster scope.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to install **custom resource definitions** (CRDs), which are a cluster-wide resource. Since it is cluster-wide, this is typically something that will be limited to cluster admins.

So apart from giving you admin privileges, the IT operators could give you specific permissions to create / edit custom resource definitions, maybe that will work.